# "database is locked" for SQLite

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6, mutex

I cannot get rid of "database is locked" error... even when I used mutex to control access to database access.

This is an event handler that is thrown asynchronously:

```
    void driver_Transaccion(object sender, AttendanceReader.MarcacionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_transaccion != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (GlobalMutex.GetMutex())
                {
                    using (var db = new DataWare.monitorEntities())
                    {
                          /* some instructions */
                          /* ..... */
                          db.SaveChanges(); /* A database lock occurs here */
                    }
                }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                ErrorLog.Save(ex);
             }
        }
    }
```

GlobalMutex.GetMutex() is defined this way:

```
public class GlobalMutex : IDisposable
{
    private Mutex _mutex;
    private bool _acquired;

    public GlobalMutex()
    {
        _mutex = new Mutex(false, "RELOJ_ELO_20181004");
        _acquired = _mutex.WaitOne();
    }

    public static IDisposable GetMutex()
    {
        return new GlobalMutex();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_acquired)
            _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        _mutex.Dispose();
        _mutex = null;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, there is another application that also write to the database.

That external application captures mutex the same way.

Maybe db.SaveChanges does not close database file before the other process tries to write ot it. Is SQLite database slow to do that? Is there an effective way to solve this?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Whatever mutexes or locking you have in your program is independent from the database file locks used by sqlite. Only one connection can write to a database at a time and it has an exclusive lock so no connections can read at the same time as the writer is writing.

Comment: And you really should show your saveChanges function, and your other program...

Comment: @Shawn SaveChanges is a function in EntityFramework... I don't have control over it. And about the other program, the code is exactly the same as the posted in the question... no difference.

Comment: @Shawn However, I guess where the problem is. Mutexes do actually work. The problem is that database file is not closed (or is slow to be closed when connection is disposed) so that when mutex is released, the other process starts its processing immediately, so when its db.SaveChanges occurs, file is locked. As an attempt, after the using monitorEntities in the other application, I am calling GC.Collect() and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); before releasing the mutex. I hope by using that, db file will be closed.

Comment: Finally... by calling GC.Collect, problem was not solved :-( error continues. Is there an effective way to close the database file and free resources?

Comment: It still does not work :-(  database file is not released :-(